# How can opening a non-existing file cause a security vulnerability?

Tags: vulnerability, file-access, race-condition

I was reading on race conditions when I encountered the paragraph below:

[image: Race conditions]

How exactly does trying to read a non-existing file cause a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

#### TOCTOU

> ```
> 1    let exists = await fs.access(path_to_file)         # FS test
> 2    if (exists) {                                      # Program test
> 3      const data = await fs.readFile(path_to_file)     # Access file
> 4    ...
> 5    }
> ```

Between line `1` where the filesystem check is done and line `3` where the file is opened, there is a *gap*.

For example: An attacker could uses this gap for dropping `path_to_file` and creates a symlink to `/etc/passwd`, your program will access the wrong file!!

More explanations: [Time-of-check to time-of-use at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)

> How exactly does trying to read a non-existing file cause a security vulnerability?

Depending on your object and flaws, ***TOCTOU*** could be used as well in read and in write mode!

- Reading and publishing secret files or
- Writing, then altering crucial files...